# How to create a table using `Proc SQL` without selecting from existing tables

Tags: sql, sas, proc-sql

What is the SAS version of "`select from dual`"? I want to create a table using `Proc SQL` without selecting from excisting tables. for instance. Basically I want something like:

```
PROC SQL;
  CREATE TABLE tmptable AS
  SELECT 1 AS myvar FROM dual;
QUIT;
```

This does not work. What choices do I have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there is anything like select from DUAL in SAS.
But you could try if this helps you:

```
proc sql inobs=1; /* limit read to only one observations */
  select 1 as myvar
  from sashelp.table /* or any table desired */
  ; 
quit;
```

The INOBS=1 makes sure you only read one row from  `sashelp.table`, so you only have one result.

Answer (score 1):

As you state, SAS `Proc SQL` does not have a premade `DUAL` table.

You can use `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements instead.

Example

```
proc sql;
  create table want (x num);

  insert into want values (1);

  insert into want 
    values(2)
    values(3)
  ;
quit;
```

or create your own `DUAL` first (perhaps if migrating SQL code into SAS `Proc SQL`)

```
proc sql;
  create table dual (dummy char(1)); insert into dual values ('X');

  CREATE TABLE tmptable AS
  SELECT 1 AS myvar FROM dual;
quit;
```